# Specific website does not load on single network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, home-networking

There are a few threads with questions similar to this one, but none that I've found which are the same and resolve my question.

I am having trouble accessing just one particular website from my computer and mobile phone, but only on one particular network (my home). When I try to access it from Google Chrome, I get a message: "This site can't be reached [... website] took too long to respond." This problem persists even if I use different browsers, and also on different devices. If I use a VPN, however, everything loads fine.

I assume that this means that it is the network itself which needs to be adjusted, but I don't know what needs to be done.

Comment: You would contact your ISP and/or if it's a private network you are connecting to the Administrator, to determine the reason the website is blocked.  By the use of a proxy, you have confirmed that either the domain is purposefully blocked or there is a DNS issue.  As a normal user, only the DNS issue, can be solved by you by the use of a different DNS provider.  [1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1/) is a good choice.

Comment: Show us a failing traceroute to the site in question from your home network, and a working traceroute to the site in question from somewhere else. It could be that your ISP has a broken route to whatever network that one website is on. Or it could be that the one website uses a CDN whose local edge node is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can try:

1. I've seen cases where the home router DNS messes up and needs a reset. Alternatively, you could set a different DNS provider from within your operating system, like Ramhound suggested. Remember to do this for every system of interest.
2. Try leaving your modem / router off overnight to get a new DHCP lease from your ISP. Perhaps your existing IP is blocked and a new one will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can tracert the website to see what part of the network from your device to the website is wrong, and then decide whether to adjust the network.

Also, some specific websites are not open to everyone due to confidentiality and policy reasons. If possible, I recommend that you still use VPN to access it.